# Nodejs - Catch filesize error with multer

Tags: node.js, multer

I use this code "multer" to upload files to my server. Even if i have the limit filesize it just ignore it and upload the file.

```
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "uploads/");
    },
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024
    }
});

const upload = multer(
{
    storage: storage
}
).single("file");

router.post("/files/postfile", function (req: any, res: any, next) {

    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.json({error: err});
        }
        return res.json({success: true});
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024
    }
}).single("file");
```

Remove the `limits` from `multer.diskStorage`

Answer (score -2):

Your code is very inefficient.

```
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "uploads/");
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024
    }
});

router.post("/files/postfile", upload.single("file"); function (req: any, res: any, next) {
    // . . . . code . . . .

});
```

By using middleware, you can write efficient code
I recommend this method.
and If filename attribute use when multer.diskStorage() call, you can file name chage.

```
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "uploads/");
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, 'unique_name.jpg'); # example: timestamp, utc, etc
    },
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024
    }
```

file name can duplicate.

Comment: and how can i catch the error inside my route? first i was using the code like you but i couldn't find a way to catch the error inside the route

Comment: I take this example from the official site for catching errors. https://github.com/expressjs/multer#error-handling

Comment: yes... i want my route to send a appropriate response for the upload error

Comment: const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024
    }
}).single("file");

router.post("/files/postfile", function (req: any, res: any, next) {
    upload(req, res, function(err){

   });
});



This seems to be the case..

Comment: sorry. I don't know that you want to error handling.

If you encounter problems while using middleware, internally use next (err) to handle errors.